# How to do an animation for iOS on XCODE9

Tags: ios, xcode9

I'm trying to do an animation on XCODE 9 but it returns me a Nil value, does anybody knows what can be doing that Problem? First I have created an **IBOutlet** reference, then the code shown belong. Thanks a Lot.

```
@IBOutlet weak var ImageView: UIImageView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ImageView.image = UIImage.animatedImageNamed("start", duration: 1.0)

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBOutlet var imageView: WKInterfaceImage!

override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

   imageView.setImageNamed("start")

   imageView.startAnimatingWithImages(
        in: NSRange(location: 0, length: 20),
        duration: 7,
        repeatCount: 1)

 }
```

Comment: Even if your code solves the OP issue, it is recommended to add some of the descriptive text to your code snippet.